# navbar links dont appear iphone

Tags: iphone, twitter-bootstrap

so im in the process of developing my own website and understanding bootstrap. just recently uploaded the files to the free server and i see that everything that ive worked on its there and it looks just like i see it on my laptop, except of course for a few things that i cannot make work yet like : the position of logo on the navbar and links not being active when pressed. anyway when i checked on my phone to see how it looked like i couldnt see the links on the navbar, all i could see was a square with lines inside but when i touched it nothing appeared. so what should i do? am i missing a something?

Comment: Hello Eduardo. You will find that questions like yours don't go very well on StackOverflow. The reason is you have provided no information that we can use to help you solve your problem. If you would like to get a good answer I would suggest you provide a link to your site, a screenshot of what it should look like (maybe from your laptop) and a screenshot of what it looks like on your phone. If you have made attempts to fix it please include what you have done. Also if possible include the code! Thanks, and good luck with your problem.

Comment: Yes!! I forgot! So sorry malaya.site11.com

Comment: Will include code later im just not at my home right now... Sorry man

Comment: Not my loss! Don't worry. just send me a comment here and I'll try to help!

Comment: site: http://malaya.site11.com

http://malaya.site11.com/screens/
included very briefly how i think should look like. code and screens on phone and laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has a mobile navigation built into it but it requires javascript.  Ensure you have JS enabled and have included the collapse.js file:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse